# Xcode: Keyboard shortcuts for selecting changes to commit or discard?

Tags: xcode

In the Xcode 7 commit confirmation dialog*, you can use the mouse to select pop-up menus in the central gutter to exclude specific changes by marking them as "Don't commit" or "Discard change".

Can keyboard shortcuts be used to mark a change as "Don't commit" or "Discard change"?

* By 'commit confirmation dialog' I mean the dialog that appears after choosing the *Source -> Commit...* menu item. It allows you to review changes before committing them to your source repository.

Answer (score 2):

After clicking on the central gutter, or on a specific change therein, the up and down arrow keys can be used to navigate to and highlight a particular change.

"Don't commit" can be performed on the selected change by pressing the space bar. (Pressing it again toggles this setting.)

"Discard change" can be performed on the selected change by pressing the delete key.

I haven't been able to find these commands in Xcode's *Key Bindings* preference panel so I assume they're not customisable.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing [space] will deselect the change (Don't Commit), pressing [backspace] will remove the change (Discard Change).